# local host ip (127.0.0.1) is not working on google-compute-engine

Tags: python, python-requests, localhost, google-compute-engine

I've exposed an URL (http://127.0.0.1:5000/daily) but in Google Compute Engine (GCE) I am not getting the values. If I access this URL through requests in simple python program, it is running efficiently.

```
import requests
import json
req=requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/daily')

a = json.loads(req.text)

discount_rate = a['data']['policy_rate']
six_months_kibor = a['data']['today_kibor_rate']
dollar_to_pkr= a['data']['today_usd_rate']

print(discount_rate, six_months_kibor, dollar_to_pkr)
```

ERROR which I am receiving from GCE is:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f93526c16a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /daily (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f93526c16a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    req=requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/daily')
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev_baseh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /daily (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f93526c16a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused', ))
```

I don't the reason, that why it is not running over GCE. 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: where did you expose IP 127.0.0.1 ? 127.0.0.1 can be accessed only from other program on the same computer as your exposed server. It can't be accessed from another computers.

Comment: Got it, I am using my public ip address but how can I access the values which are available at 127.0.0.1:5000/daily/ ?

Comment: if you run own local server then first you have to run server with IP `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` so it will use all network cards (NIC) installed in computer instead of virtual card (loopback) and other computers in local network will have access to this server. To access from internet you would have to find your external IP. It is not IP of your computer but IP of external router which redirects all connections to your computer. You can use web pages which shows your external IP. But usually router redirects only common ports like 80 but not 5000 so better use port 80 in local server.

Comment: you can also use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your local server on internet - `ngrok http 5000` - and it will create random URL for your local server. If you want contant URL then you would have to pay.

Comment: with free version of ngrok is one problem - it creates new random URL when you restart ngrok.

Answer (score 2):

The IP address 127.0.0.1 refers to the local IP address of your machine. So if you run a python program on the same machine where you're running that server, it would be able to access that address since both have the same IP address.

When you try to access 127.0.0.1 from GCP, what is happening is GCP is locally trying to access the port 5000 and not your machine's port 5000.

You would need to figure out the public facing IP address of the machine where you're running the server. If it's on your computer, you could just Google, "what is my IP" and get it.

Comment: Got it, I am using my public ip address but how can I access the values which are available at 127.0.0.1:5000/daily/ ?

Comment: You would need to go into your router setting and verify that port 5000 is being "port forwarded" from your local machine so that it can be accessed from the outside world.